# How to add a globally frameset backgound image for a main page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp, frameset

I want to add a backgound page for my Jsp page, In this i used a frameset when i used a backgound image for a main frameset its showing problem in FF and IE, 
Code Is:

```
<frameset cols="*,1020px,*" border="0" class="bg" style="images/background.jpg">
    <frame src="about:blank"  /> 
        <!-- Next frameset is centered horizontally and have width:1020px --> 
        <!-- Tested in IE8,Chrome13,Opera11.50,Safari5,FF7 --> 
        <frameset rows="8%,*" border="0"  >  
            <frame src="HeaderUi.jsp" name="header" scrolling="no" style="border-bottom:5px solid #630000;" /> 
                <frameset cols="220px,540px,*" border="0" style="background:#000">  
                    <frame src="webSearchUi" name="search" />   
                <frameset rows="65%,*" border="0" >       
                    <frame src="webMainPageUi" name="mainPage" scrolling="yes" style="border:1px dotted #7D7D7D; border-top:0px; border-bottom:0px dashed #5c5c5c" />        <frame src="webEventPanelUi" name="eventPanel" style="border:1px dotted #7D7D7D; border-top:1px solid #7D7D7D; border-bottom:0px dashed #5c5c5c" />      </frameset>   
                    <frame src="webDataPanelUi" name="dataPanel" style="border-style:solid;border-width:0pt;border-color:66CC33">
                </frameset>
                    <frame src="about:blank" class="Bg" />   
                </frameset> 
        </frameset>  
<frame src="about:blank" /> </frameset>
```

In This Code i want to use a background-image.
Thanks in Advance
Mayur Mate

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use attribute *style* you should write there css styles in the following way:

style="property1: value1; property2: value2"

in your case the code should be:

```html
<frameset cols="*,1020px,*" border="0" class="bg" style="background: url('images/background.jpg');">
```

Comment: For framesets this does not works in browsers except maybe FF. And for background url image is not need to use quotes. Right syntax for: `style="background: url(images/background.jpg);"`

Comment: You are not right. Yes, in our case it's not required to use quotes because there are no spaces in the url. But if they are present - you must use quotes. Please read specification [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#uri)